# protractor js, repeater not iterating through the 'result'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

in my protractor.test.js

```
it('should make sure that there are listings on the page', function()
{
    var count = element.all(by.repeater('res in result'));
    count.then(function(result){
    expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    }, 5000);

})
```

and in my index.html

```
  <div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-click="post($event,res)"  ng-repeat="res in result"  ng-controller="recommendedJobsCtrl" ui-sref="menu.jobDetails" >
```

the issue is it says expected 0 to be greater than 0. but when i change it to res in tests or any other word it still gives me the same answer. I don't think it's reading my result

Comment: I don't see any issue in your code. The elements are probably not yet created when the test is executed. Try to wait for at least one element.

Comment: @FlorentB. Isn't the 5000 considered a waiting period? Do you have another method of approaching the wait ?

Comment: The second argument should be the optional rejection callback. So no, it won't wait 5000ms. Have a look at `browser.wait`: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait

Comment: @FlorentB. can you please give me an example

Answer (score 2):

I agree with part of [igniteram's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38632219/6201042) that you should use `count()`, but you cannot use Expected Conditions on an [ElementArrayFinder](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) (which is what `element.all` returns).

Instead, you could also try using a helper function, taken from [alecxe's answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34293470/6201042).

```
// in my helper file Util.js

// wait for X number of elements
Util.prototype.presenceOfAll = function (elem, num) {
    console.log('Waiting for elements ' + elem.locator() + ' to have a count of ' + num);
    return browser.wait(function () {
        return elem.count().then(function (count) {
            return count >= num;
        });
    }, 5000, 'Failed waiting for ' + elem.locator() + ' to have ' + num + ' total items');
};
```

Usage:

```
var userNav = element.all(by.css('li.navbar-item'));
// wait for userNav to have 4 elements/buttons
Util.presenceOfAll(userNav, 4).then(function () {
    // your code
});
```

Also note that Protractor patches `expect` to implicitly handle promises, so you don't need to use `.then()` after `.count()` unless you are doing something else.  So applying that to your code, I would modify it this way:

```
it('should make sure that there are listings on the page', function() {
    var count = element.all(by.repeater('res in result'));
    Util.presenceOfAll(count, 5); // change 5 for whatever number should be there
    expect(count.count()).toEqual(5);

    // could also have been written as this since presenceOfAll returns a promise
    Util.presenceOfAll(count, 5).then(function() { 
         expect(count.count()).toEqual(5);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 , thanks for correcting me. I assumed EC would work with `element.all` as well, yes it returns an `element array finder`!

Comment: @igniteram1 Ya I wish it did with work element.all :( would be very useful

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the protractor's `count()` method directly-

```
it('should make sure that there are listings on the page', function()
{
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var el = element.all(by.repeater('res in result'));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(el), 5000);
expect(el.count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
})
```

Comment: you could use explicit wait to determine the visibility, updated my answer! also please use `browser.pause` or `browser.debugger` to know what's happening at that particular element.

Comment: you should try what @Gunderson suggested!

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is that you never actually count the elements you've selected.

```
it('should make sure that there are listings on the page', function()
{
    var results = element.all(by.repeater('res in result'));
    results.count().then(function(count){
    expect(count).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    }, 5000);

})
```

The above example should work for you. Note that I changed some of the variable names for clarity.